# uwp datagrid sort by parameter

Tags: datagrid, uwp-xaml, columnsorting

I have a UWP app that reads data from a SQL database and displays it in a Microsoft Toolkit DataGrid. I have used V4 and the pre-release V5 of the datagrid. You can sort by clicking on a column heading, but that just fires an event which you then have to handle in code. I have done this, and it all works, but I have to handle each column individually. I can pass the selected column to the code, but is there a way to then pass that to the sort routine, so that there is only one set of code?

In main code:

```
// Populate list of column names for use in searching
List<String> elementNames = new List<String>();
    Type type = typeof(ExpiringCustomer);
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        this.elementNames.Add(property.Name);
    }
```

This is the sorting routine:

```
private void dataGrid1_Sorting(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
{

    String orderString = elementNames[e.Column.DisplayIndex];

    if (e.Column.SortDirection == null || e.Column.SortDirection == DataGridSortDirection.Descending)
    {
        if (e.Column.Tag.ToString() == "Customer")
        {                    
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ExpiringCustomer>(from item in expCustomers
                orderby item.customerName ascending
                select item);
            }
            else
            if (e.Column.Tag.ToString() == "UserCount")
            {
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ExpiringCustomer>(from item in expCustomers
                    orderby item.userCount ascending
                    select item);
                    else
                    {
                        if ............
                        etc. etc.
```

I would like to be able to make use of 'orderString' so that I don't have to repeat the sort code.

Comment: Your sort code is correct, but you have no need sort all columns within one header click. And I don't  know what's the mean of `orderString` that you mentioned ?

Comment: Do the `orderString` like the [this](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid)?

Comment: @Nico: At the top of the code above, orderString retrieves the identifier of the column that has been clicked. I want to use that (or some other method) to have just ONE sort routine that will handle ALL columns (orderby <<orderString>> ascending instead of orderby item.customerName ascending AND orderby item.userCount ascending). At present, I have just 4 columns, but I am using this as a reference for other projects where I could have a larger number of columns and don't want to have separate code for each one. Then, if the number of columns changes, no modifications are needed in the code.